# How to deep clone Messaging.SingleEmailMessage?

Tags: apex, email, singleemailmessage, clone

## Problem Statement

I'm working on a fluent email builder, but I've hit a bit of a snag. Namely, there does not seem to be any *simple* way to completely clone a `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage` instance without sharing a reference.

Why would I want to do such a thing? Well, it seems pretty common to have a collection of emails with  common properties such as subject, recipients, template, etc.

## Attempts

#### Serialization

The simplest attempt code-wise would be to serialize and de-serialize to break the reference:

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage clone = (Messaging.SingleEmailMessage)
    JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(email), Messaging.SingleEmailMessage.class);
```

However, this code throws a run-time error:

> System.JSONException: Unrecognized field "debug" at [line:1, column:83]

Apparently it is not even possible to re-serialize back to the same type here!

#### Getters/Setters

Fine, I thought, I'll just use all of the getters and manually copy over each property:

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
// set various properties

Messaging.SingleEmailMessage clone = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
clone.setBccAddresses(message.getBccAddresses);
// and so on
```

However, a couple Boolean flags on this object lack getters:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Messaging.SingleEmailMessage].getTreatBodiesAsTemplate()
>
> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Messaging.SingleEmailMessage].getTreatTargetObjectAsRecipient()

## Question

Is there any simple or elegant way to clone a `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage` instance? I'm pursuing other design routes (like making the builder `virtual`) but it's frustrating to not be able to clone such a basic system object. The only way I can think to do it would be to pull out the properties from an untyped map, which is not a satisfying long term solution:

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String, Object>)
    JSON.deserializeUntyped(JSON.serialize(email));
Boolean treatBodiesAsTemplate = data.get('treatBodiesAsTemplate');
Boolean treatTargetObjectAsRecipient = data.get('treatTargetObjectAsRecipient');
```

Comment: Well, not sure about cloning but the `TreatTargetObjectAsRecipient` and `TreatBodiesAsTemplate` boolean flags are public and can be accessed by `email.TreatBodiesAsTemplate`.

Comment: Ah, that's strange they have a different access pattern...wasn't aware of that. That's good enough for my purposes, and I would be happy to accept that as an answer.

Comment: yup, been there, faced that! Anyway, glad I was of help. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your getter/setter approach, the `TreatTargetObjectAsRecipient` and `TreatBodiesAsTemplate` boolean flags are having public access modifier and can be accessed as follows:

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
Boolean treatBodiesAsTemplate = email.treatBodiesAsTemplate;
Boolean treatTargetObjectAsRecipient = email.treatTargetObjectAsRecipient;
```